# Expand type class operations on elements using macros

Tags: scala, macros, typeclass, value-class

Assuming the following setup:

```
trait A[L] { def op(l1:L, l2:L): L }
trait E[L] { def op(l:L): L }

implicit def some2E[L:A](self:L) =  new E[L] { def op(other:L) =      
  implicitly[A[L]].op(self,other) }
```

Is there a way to directly expand `m op n` to `a.op(m,n)`, in a context where `a` is the appropriate implicit `A`, using macros or at least avoid the additional object creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the implicit parameter to the `op` method, you can use a value class to prevent the additional object creation:

```
implicit class some2E[L](val self: L) extends AnyVal {
 def op(other: L)(implicit x: A[L]) = x.op(self, other)
}
```

Hotspot will probably inline the call to the`op` defined in `some2E`, so you will end up with `a.op(m, n)`.

Comment: Thanks, I came up with this also. Performance wise this brings me half way to writing `a.op(m,n)` directly for non-primitive `L` for primitie `L` it's still a factor of 20 slower probably because there is a lot of boxing going on in the bytecode.